# How to get value of js variable which is no "key"

Tags: javascript

I want to get the "mainAttributeXX" part from js variable which is like next

```
varList = new Object();
varList = {
    "mainAttribute01":{text:"abcd", attribute1:"3", attribute2:"1"},
    "mainAttribute02":{text:"abcd", attribute1:"2", attribute2:"2"},
    "mainAttribute03":{text:"abcd", attribute1:"1", attribute2:"3"},
}
```

I tried this and got error.

```
document.write(varList[0]);
```

and I want the result to be like this:

```
mainAttribute01
```

I couldn't change the original data structure, because the data is from another site.

Comment: Loop with `for (var key in varList)`

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use object.keys

```
Object.keys(varList)[0]
```

Comment: Pretty neat, I didn't know about this. +1